# Gmaps4Rails Custom InfoWindow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am getting gmaps4rails working on my project, but I'm struggling to customize the aspect of the info window. I followed the tutorial found in the wiki and I understand most of it except the callback part for the InfoBox that is a bit confusing for me, an inexperienced JS programmer. When I click on the marker I only get the 'x' (close) button but no text is displayed or color as expected. Here is my code:

In post.rb:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  # add here whatever html content you desire, it will be displayed when users clicks on the marker
  "<h4>#{self.title}</h4>"
end
```

In posts.js.coffee:

```
Gmaps.map.infobox = (boxText) ->
  content: boxText
  disableAutoPan: false
  maxWidth: 0
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
  zIndex: null
  boxStyle:
    background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
    opacity: 0.75
    width: "280px"

  closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
  closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
  infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
  isHidden: false
  pane: "floatPane"
  enableEventPropagation: false
```

In gmaps4rails.css

```
.yellow { border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px; }
```

In my view:

```
= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"custom_infowindow_class" => "yellow" } })
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction as this is my first time working with maps. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

My Results:

http://postimage.org/image/45feoz3kl/

EDIT 2:

I dont want to abuse of you but once I understand what is going on I will be good by my own, for now it is just worst. Now it doesn't even render and I am getting a bunch of errors. This is my code:

```
= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"custom_infowindow_class" => "yellow" } })
- content_for :scripts
  :javascript
    Gmaps.map.infobox = function(boxText) {
      return {
        content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: {
          background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
          ,opacity: 0.75
          ,width: "280px"
          }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
    }};
```

Error:

"unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end" in the line of the return statement.

Comment: Seems fine. Last time I saw this kind of issue, was due to css.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately I can't find the problem. My files are as shown above and it is not working. Do you have a working example on a gist that you could share? Thank you once again. EDIT: I checked the css and it is working fine when applied to other boxes, so I don't think it is a css problem.

Comment: do you have a visible url for this page?

Comment: do you have any js error in console?

Comment: I only have my site running locally, but I posted the warnings I found in the console in the original post. Also I found that the JS generated in the HTML is fine as shown in my third edit!

Comment: ok, any error in your javascript console inside browser?

Comment: There is one! "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'infobox' of undefined" I guess infobox doesn't exist right? I thought it was included in the gem. How can I import it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few comments, I finally understand (even it was obvious after all...):

`Gmaps.map` is created on the fly when the page is loaded. So whenever you want to add properties to this object, you must add it **after** the `gmaps` call **and** in a `content_for :scripts`.

in your code:

```
= gmaps()

- content_for :scripts do
  :javascript
    Gmaps.map.infobox = function(....
```

Comment: I am sorry for my incompetence, but I am not that experienced so I really dont understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate a little bit more? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for guiding me, but could you please check out one last time my original post? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it working. Hope I can make it back to you when I am more experienced. I appreciate everything you did. Have a good day!